gcloud app deploy fails with Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied
we have several projects running on GAE Python Standard Environment and can be deployed without problems.
New projects now suffer this error in Google Cloud Build when doing just a simple gcloud app deploy:
ERROR: failed to create image cache: accessing cache image "eu.gcr.io/my-project/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest": connect to repo store "eu.gcr.io/my-project/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest": GET https://eu.gcr.io/v2/token?scope=repository%3Amy-project%2Fapp-engine-tmp%2Fbuild-cache%2Fdefault%2Fttl-7d%3Apull&service=eu.gcr.io: DENIED: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/my-project/locations/europe/repositories/eu.gcr.io" (or it may not exist)

(I've replaced the customer's project name by my-project here).
Here's the entire log:
starting build "8bd2df7e-727a-4b3c-a1c1-e40e79749385"

FETCHSOURCE
BUILD
Starting Step #0 - "fetch"
Step #0 - "fetch": Pulling image: eu.gcr.io/serverless-runtimes/utilities/gcs-fetcher:base_20240804_18_04_RC00
Step #0 - "fetch": base_20240804_18_04_RC00: Pulling from serverless-runtimes/utilities/gcs-fetcher
Step #0 - "fetch": Digest: sha256:c44f835ee17e722f0d65f14b44900a0ca9125ce3f07fa88135e266d1a3ba788f
Step #0 - "fetch": Status: Downloaded newer image for eu.gcr.io/serverless-runtimes/utilities/gcs-fetcher:base_20240804_18_04_RC00
Step #0 - "fetch": eu.gcr.io/serverless-runtimes/utilities/gcs-fetcher:base_20240804_18_04_RC00
Step #0 - "fetch": Fetching manifest gs://staging.my-project.appspot.com/ae/f587cadf-c03f-49d8-aec5-bc88b36e9c3b/manifest.json.
Step #0 - "fetch": Processing 2581 files.
Step #0 - "fetch": ******************************************************
Step #0 - "fetch": Status:                      SUCCESS
Step #0 - "fetch": Started:                     2024-08-30T14:42:18Z
Step #0 - "fetch": Completed:                   2024-08-30T14:42:19Z
Step #0 - "fetch": Requested workers:    200
Step #0 - "fetch": Actual workers:       200
Step #0 - "fetch": Total files:         2581
Step #0 - "fetch": Total retries:          0
Step #0 - "fetch": GCS timeouts:           0
Step #0 - "fetch": MiB downloaded:        17.63 MiB
Step #0 - "fetch": MiB/s throughput:      12.70 MiB/s
Step #0 - "fetch": Time for manifest:     78.27 ms
Step #0 - "fetch": Total time:             1.48 s
Step #0 - "fetch": ******************************************************
Finished Step #0 - "fetch"
Starting Step #1 - "pre-buildpack"
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Pulling image: eu.gcr.io/serverless-runtimes/google-22-full/builder/python:python_20240826_RC00
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": python_20240826_RC00: Pulling from serverless-runtimes/google-22-full/builder/python
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 9b857f539cb1: Already exists
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": bd112cf3e6c8: Already exists
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 36329e5c2232: Already exists
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 5df02f4e8036: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": abfee54d7c13: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 946468808bb6: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 2868e0ed0081: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 56f6786be55b: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": c218a6da1a54: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 06f428a8446f: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 8416fcb4dc1e: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": c477ba28bed9: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 6fdb610addcc: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": cfc5022d3a16: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 25b2039efd92: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": e89b35b3411b: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": f0afa281882b: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 28474b7a68af: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": e7103d6f5cd4: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": efcc4b761029: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": e1d3292d585f: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": c72c9d49c9f3: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 8f26cb428371: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 9da0c55b4d56: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 34ce8ba30961: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 4f4fb700ef54: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 2868e0ed0081: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 56f6786be55b: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": c218a6da1a54: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 06f428a8446f: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 8416fcb4dc1e: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": c477ba28bed9: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 6fdb610addcc: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": cfc5022d3a16: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 25b2039efd92: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": e89b35b3411b: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": f0afa281882b: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 28474b7a68af: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": e7103d6f5cd4: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": efcc4b761029: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": e1d3292d585f: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": c72c9d49c9f3: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 8f26cb428371: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 9da0c55b4d56: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 34ce8ba30961: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 4f4fb700ef54: Waiting
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": abfee54d7c13: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 5df02f4e8036: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 5df02f4e8036: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 946468808bb6: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 946468808bb6: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 2868e0ed0081: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 2868e0ed0081: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 5df02f4e8036: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": abfee54d7c13: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 56f6786be55b: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 56f6786be55b: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 06f428a8446f: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 946468808bb6: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": c218a6da1a54: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": c218a6da1a54: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 2868e0ed0081: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": c477ba28bed9: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": c477ba28bed9: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 6fdb610addcc: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 6fdb610addcc: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 8416fcb4dc1e: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 8416fcb4dc1e: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 56f6786be55b: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 25b2039efd92: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 25b2039efd92: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": cfc5022d3a16: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": cfc5022d3a16: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": e89b35b3411b: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": e89b35b3411b: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": f0afa281882b: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": f0afa281882b: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 28474b7a68af: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 28474b7a68af: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": e7103d6f5cd4: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": e7103d6f5cd4: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": efcc4b761029: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": e1d3292d585f: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": e1d3292d585f: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": c72c9d49c9f3: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 9da0c55b4d56: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": c218a6da1a54: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 34ce8ba30961: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 34ce8ba30961: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 8f26cb428371: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 8f26cb428371: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 06f428a8446f: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 4f4fb700ef54: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 4f4fb700ef54: Download complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 8416fcb4dc1e: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": c477ba28bed9: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 6fdb610addcc: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": cfc5022d3a16: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 25b2039efd92: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": e89b35b3411b: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": f0afa281882b: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 28474b7a68af: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": e7103d6f5cd4: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": efcc4b761029: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": e1d3292d585f: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": c72c9d49c9f3: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 8f26cb428371: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 9da0c55b4d56: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 34ce8ba30961: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": 4f4fb700ef54: Pull complete
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Digest: sha256:2ef3f88f95b6f6a7821bee467d7b49a87bea54ee8bb18aa99fd97fc5688f79b3
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Status: Downloaded newer image for eu.gcr.io/serverless-runtimes/google-22-full/builder/python:python_20240826_RC00
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": eu.gcr.io/serverless-runtimes/google-22-full/builder/python:python_20240826_RC00
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Preparing directory /layers
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Preparing directory /workspace
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Preparing directory /builder/home
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Preparing directory /builder/outputs
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Preparing directory /platform/env
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable BUILDER_OUTPUT to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_RUNTIME to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_LABEL_BUILDER_VERSION to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_LABEL_BUILDER_IMAGE to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_LABEL_RUN_IMAGE to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_LABEL_SOURCE to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_RUNTIME_IMAGE_REGION to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable X_GOOGLE_SKIP_RUNTIME_LAUNCH to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GAE_APP_ENGINE_APIS to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable GOOGLE_ENTRYPOINT to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Passing build environment variable X_GOOGLE_TARGET_PLATFORM to buildpacks
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": Checking if image eu.gcr.io/my-project/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest exists
Step #1 - "pre-buildpack": WARNING: Failed to reuse previous cache image; will not affect current build: GET https://eu.gcr.io/v2/token?scope=repository%3Amy-project%2Fapp-engine-tmp%2Fbuild-cache%2Fdefault%2Fttl-7d%3Apull&service=eu.gcr.io: DENIED: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/my-project/locations/europe/repositories/eu.gcr.io" (or it may not exist)
Finished Step #1 - "pre-buildpack"
Starting Step #2 - "build"
Step #2 - "build": Already have image (with digest): eu.gcr.io/serverless-runtimes/google-22-full/builder/python:python_20240826_RC00
Step #2 - "build": ERROR: failed to create image cache: accessing cache image "eu.gcr.io/my-project/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest": connect to repo store "eu.gcr.io/my-project/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d:latest": GET https://eu.gcr.io/v2/token?scope=repository%3Amy-project%2Fapp-engine-tmp%2Fbuild-cache%2Fdefault%2Fttl-7d%3Apull&service=eu.gcr.io: DENIED: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/my-project/locations/europe/repositories/eu.gcr.io" (or it may not exist)
Finished Step #2 - "build"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "eu.gcr.io/serverless-runtimes/google-22-full/builder/python:python_20240826_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1

I don't know what I am doing wrong, and already tried to equip the user I'm using for deployment with several admin rights regarding artifact registry.
Can anyone help?

Seems like you missed adding the Cloud build service account with artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts permission. The solution was to provide the service account with the artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts permission. Also can you elaborate on your issue by sharing the steps you are following about your infrastructure to replicate the issue and the document you are following?

Hello sandeep-vokkareni, thanks for your help! That seems to work. Why is this role now required, and why are older projects and their service accounts not affected?

As suggested in the comments, It Seems like you missed adding the Cloud build service account with artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts permission. The solution was to provide the service account with the artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts permission. This issue seems to be with the Cloud Build Service Account, not your Service Account. You can identify the Cloud Build Service Account with
NUMBER=$(gcloud projects describe ${PROJECT} --format="value(projectNumber)") 

Then enumerate its roles using
gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} --flatten="bindings[].members" --filter="bindings.members:${NUMBER}@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com" --format="value(bindings.role)"

Then check whether the permission artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts is included.
This is due to the change in Cloud Build Service Account. Check the note in the Documentation.

Note: The Cloud Build default service account used to run builds is being changed.

For more information see Cloud Build service account change.
